# Pass json object one component to another vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vuejs I want to pass an JSON object to another component within same vue instance. following show the my code. from component add-user to component view-user. I tried vue props but it didn't work
Thank you very much.

```js
Vue.component('view-users',{
  props:['user'],
  template: '<span>{{ user.name }}</span>'
}); 

Vue.component('add-user',{
 data: function(){
    return  {
        user:{
           name:'jhon',
            age:'29',
          }
      }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<add-user></add-user>

<view-users></view-users>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props are mostly for passing data from parent components to child components, and a child component cannot directly modify the passed data and reflect the changes on parent components. In order to pass data around every component, a good way to do it is using `Vuex`.

First you create the state, possibly like

```
const state = {
  user:{
    name:'john',
    age:'29',
  }
}
```

And for the simplest case, that you are not doing anything asynchronous for now, you modify the state through `mutations`:

```
const mutations = {
  CHANGE_NAME(state, payload) {
    state.user.name = payload
  },
  CHANGE_AGE(state, payload) {
    state.user.age = payload
  }
}
```

With all these in place you can create the Vue store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations
})
```

Then use it in your Vue instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: { ... },
  store,
  // ...
})
```

Finally, in your components, you can access and modify the state as follows:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  data() {
    return {
      // ...
    }
  },
  computed() {
    user() {
      // this is one way to do, you can also check out mapstate
      return this.$store.state.user
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // you can also check out mapMutations
    changeName(val) { this.$store.dispatch('CHANGE_NAME', val) },
    changeAge(val) { this.$store.dispatch('CHANGE_AGE', val) },
  }
})
```

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/teepluss/zfab6tzp/6/

You can also use EventBus if you app is not too big ([tutorial](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) and [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events)). And for `Vuex`, you can check out how to use [state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) and [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) here.

Comment: Thank you very much. you saved my time :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use variable in many component, vuex could be better idea. But if you want to pass value to component, you can use like that

```
<div id="app">
  <add-user :user=user></add-user>
  <view-users :user=user></view-users>
</div>

import AddUser from '../add-user.vue'
import ViewUser from '../view-users.vue'

var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    components: {
     'add-user': AddUser,
     'view-users': ViewUser
    }
});
```

in view-user or add-user component you can declare like that

```
<template><span>{{ user.name }}</span></template>
<script>
    export default {
      props: {
        user: {
          type:'your type',
          required: true/false
        }
      },
      ...
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple external state management system.
[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch)

Or you can use event handling to emit an event from one component and listen for the event in another component. [Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Also have a look at this blog post regarding sharing data between components. [Link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-between-components/2421/2)