# Pass data from parent to child in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I started working on a small project using **Vue.js** and **Laravel**, i would like to know how can i pass data from the **parent component** to the **child**: here is an example of what i have

**Index.vue** **page** :

```
import modal from './modal';

export default {
    components: { modal},
    data: function () {
         names: {'John','Doe'}
    }
}
```

i would like to send **names object** that i have in my **index** page to the modal, that i have imported in my index.vue as you can you see

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505160/pass-json-object-one-component-to-another-vuejs

Comment: not clear for me :( a little complicated

Comment: Not directly related to your question but the `return` statement is missing in your `data` function: `data: function(){ return { names: ['John', 'Doe'] } }` (note that I changed names into an array). As for passing down the _names_ to the `modal` components, can you share your `modal.vue` to show the props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended in most cases that you pass data with a prop from parent to child.

---

**Example:**

Parent component passes names as a prop to a child component:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <child-component 
    :childNames="names"
   />
 </div>
</template

<script>
 import childComponent from '@/components/childComponent'
 components: {
    childComponent
 }
 export default {
  data: function () {
     names: {'John','Doe'}
  }
 }
</script>
```

Child component registers props, now you could access `childNames` which would be the data (`names`) coming from your parent:

```
<script>
 export default {
  props: {
    childNames: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

---

For your reference - more about [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).